# Refactor nested routes for common default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring, rails-routing

I have some routes for an API which all have the same defaults (`format: :json`):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users,    only: [:index, :show, :update],           defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :items,    only: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy], defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :posts,    only: [:index, :show, :update],           defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :show, :update],           defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :flags,    only: [:index, :show, :update, :create],  defaults: { format: :json }
  end
end
```

Is there a way to refactor/DRY the code to set the `defaults` (or even the `only`) in just one place for only this set of routes?  The app also serves HTML at other routes, so it can't be a blanket setting for the whole app.

Comment: Move defaults: {format: :json} at namespace level. Namespace have it as an option.

Comment: Yep, this works. If you want to add as an answer I'll be happy to mark it. Should have tried this on my own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `defaults: {format: :json}` and the common `only` options at namespace level. Namespace have them as an option.

```
 namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, only: [:index, :show, :update]  do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users  
    resources :items,   only: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy]
    resources :posts
    resources :comments
    resources :flags,    only: [:index, :show, :update, :create]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works for the common `only` options

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator like the following:

```
[:users, :items, :posts, :comments, :flags].each do |res|
  resources res, only:[...], defaults: {}
end
```

but I see you have different only so you can also pass it to iterator